# How can I develop custom cop and ensure it passes `zeitwerk:check`

Tags: ruby, rubocop, zeitwerk

According to this site https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/development.html#implementation, it says cop code will be like this.

```rb
module RuboCop
  module Cop
    module Style
      class SimplifyNotEmptyWithAny < Base
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I followed it in `Project Root/lib/rubocop/cop/style/simplify_not_empty_with_any.rb`.

But when I command `rails zeitwerk:check`, it did not work.

```
Hold on, I am eager loading the application.
bin/rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RuboCop::Cop::Style::Base (NameError)

      class SimplifyNotEmptyWithAny < Base
                                      ^^^^
Did you mean?  Base64
```

How can I solve it?

Do you have any ideas?

I tried reuiqre 'rubocop' or require 'rubocop/cop/base' but it did not solve.

[UPDATE] I tried it `class SimplifyNotEmptyWithAny < RuboCop::Cop::Base` but got same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with this one,

```
module RuboCop
  module Cop
    module Style
      class SimplifyNotEmptyWithAny < RuboCop::Cop::Base
      ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I also tried that, but unfortunately it did not work as well.
`NameError: uninitialized constant RuboCop::Cop::Base (NameError)`
Same error here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer.

1. File path should be like this `lib/rubo_cop/cop/style/simplify_not_empty_with_any.rb` (because of pascal case of RuboCop)
2. It need the line `require 'rubocop'` at the beginning.

   - but if you have 2 files of custom cop, no need to write second file. So I recommend that would be better to write in `config/environments/test.rb`

FYI: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/discussions/12517